# парсинг json java, android/web

Tags: java, json, веб-программирование

Помогите, пожалуйста, как я могу создать приложения для парсинга и выведения следующей инфы в java?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я знаю ответы на вопросы самостоятельно изучив данные, но как я могу создать приложение, делающее это автоматически?

1. Найти и вывести самое крупное количество участников команды это member_id в array group_id?
   (Ответ 7, в третей группе)
2. Самого быстрого участника из всех групп.
   (Ответ мембер_ид 8)

Может есть какие темы, чтобы я изучил или литература? Взаимодействует ли это как то с set/get?

Comment: Смотрите в сторону библиотеки `jackson`. Создаете классы на основе вашего `json`-а и отдаете в библиотеку. На выходе получаете объекты и при помочи циклов или стримов фильтруете данные как Вам нужно.

Comment: на сайте же есть много похожих вопросов, просто [воспользуйтесь поиском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java%2bjson%2bandroid?tab=Votes).